# Faucet is secured in a strange way. How can I remove it?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I've replaced a decent amount of faucets but I've never seen something like this. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to remove it so I can replace it?

[image]
[image]

The faucet is broken to the point where the cold water runs full blast whenever the valve underneath the sink is on. More pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO7f1.jpg

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I inlined your images; hopefully you'll get a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is the faucet shaft threaded? It's hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: I would turn the water off, remove the upper cover and jamb nut then replace the 50c rubber washer, an entire kit of washers only costs 10$ and will save many times the price of the kit. After repairing the cold water I would probably do the hot water side also, that looks like a nice set , try to repair.

Comment: @EdBeal - Talk to my wife about that... some people just can't handle the brass and chrome combo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a faucet that is meant to be installed from the top without having to get under it to tighten nuts.  The pieces underneath that are holding in the holes look like they rotate like a toggle bolt.  Remove the handles and all the trim from the top and then look for a nut or screw that will turn to loosen/lower the locking pieces underneath.  Once it is loosened enough, the bottom pieces should rotate to be in line with the valve bodies and should pull out of the hole easily.

I've never seen a faucet like this in person, so this is an educated guess, but I'm pretty confident.

Comment: I think you are correct I have had this style in the past , this is why I suggested a 50c fix.+

Comment: I think you're right... this is an install from top. I bought a strap wrench and I'm able to loosen it from the top. I'm wondering if I can get it open to replace the cartridges. It appears to be a Moen Monticello which takes 1224. I'm trying to follow the guide [here](https://www.moen.com/customer-support/installation-help/1224-cartridge-replacement-tutorial) under section 5 but I'm not having the best luck getting to the cartridge.

Comment: If you want to repair the faucet, it sounds like Ed Beal would have some answers for you and you should create a new question.  I assumed you didn't want it any more and just wanted it removed.

Comment: Understood. I saw his comment and I wanted to entertain the possibility of both paths. I was able to remove the hot and cold portions of the faucet but I'm stuck with the center. Do you have any suggestions? My best guess is buying a pack of hex keys and shoving them down after removing the plunger.

Comment: @Haelous, that sounds like a good guess.  I'm not sure what else would rotate on it, so that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I just broke it off. Close enough. Thanks for the help!